# Genus of $f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+7z^2$

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms

What does this statement mean?

The genus of $f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+7z^2$ consists of

$M_f = <1,1,7> $ and $M_2 = <1> \perp \begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 1 \\
1 & 4 
\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: see http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Kap_First_Nontrivial_1995.pdf  and other items at my page http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/  and  a picture of me at http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/   You might start with the genus for binary forms in D. A. Cox, Primes of the form $x^2 + n y^2 \; .$

Comment: you asked about $w^2 + x^2 + 7 y^2 + 21 z^2$ a few days ago. Why are you asking about these things?